# ElasticSearch Java API with request params

Tags: java, elasticsearch

As it can read from the oficial [Java API documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/index-modules-shard-query-cache.html), We can set the "query_cache" param.

But, there is none method on [CountRequestBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/count/CountRequestBuilder.java) to set request params.

Which is the right way to set params in request from Java API?, specially for the exposed kind, the Count request.

Answer (score 1):

Count api has been removed.

The deprecated count api has been removed from the Java api, use the search api instead and set size to 0.

The following call

```
client.prepareCount(indices).setQuery(query).get();
```

can be replaced with

```
client.prepareSearch(indices).setSource(new SearchSourceBuilder().size(0).query(query)).get();
```

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_java_api_changes.html#_count_api_has_been_removed)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example for running a count query with Java:

```
CountResponse response = client.prepareCount(INDEX)
        .setQuery(new TermQueryBuilder("_type", TYPE))
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Comment: Thank you for for your support Jeff, but that is not the question, read it again please.

Answer (score 0):

As me said in #1, CountRequestBuilder doesn't has any way to specify "query_cache" param, the only one way to achieve this approach is working with SearchRequestBuilder in this way.

```
this.transportClient.prepareSearch(...).setTypes(...)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.COUNT)
                .setQuery(...)
                .setQueryCache(true)
                .execute().actionGet();
```